# Caching .jpg images from a "Tourweaver" Panorama

Tags: php, apache, caching, joomla

I have a dev site, almost complete at:  [Link to Site](http://marinasol.com)

It is rather media rich, especially the property details pages, but actually seems to load pretty quickly.  I was looking at the Network activity with the Safari Developer tool and noticed that although the css and js resources get cached after the first visit, the jpg file from the panorama iframe are not.  An example would be:
    http://marinasol.com/panoramas/Courtyard_Pano_Auto/_auto/flash/scene/pano_1/0_2_1_3.jpg

from the home page.  I don't know if this is because the pano is an iframe or because the MIME type is image/jpeg but the Resource Type is "Other".  I have an .htaccess that specifies a lot of the caching.  Just wondering if there is a way to fix that so that all of the pano images are cached after the first visit.  This would only really help with the home page.  Ditto for the audio system_music.mp3

Answer (score 0):

Try having the following in your `.htaccess` file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=200000, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Please post back here if that helps. If it doesn't, then please post the contents of your `.htaccess` file here.

Comment: If you want the entire .htaccess I can post, but it is pretty long.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seem to help.  I already have the following in the root of the site, which is part of an .htaccess generated by a Joomla! component, no .htaccess in the root of the panorama iFrame index page.

```
ExpiresByType image/bmp "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jp2 "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/pipeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/tiff "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.wap.wbmp "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.wap.wbxml "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/smil "now plus 1 month"
```

where 2592000 is 30 days, so that part seems to be working.

but if you look at the network panel for those images you see:

[image]

The thing that seems different than other cached images is that the Resource Type is "Other" rather than "image".  Looking at the other images served that are cached the MIME type is text/plain, which probably isn't right either, and the Resource Type is "image".  It looks that most of the resources that are served with the iFrame have a Resource type of "Other".

The direct link to the iframe for the sample pano is:

[Link to iFrame](http://marinasol.com/panoramas/Courtyard_Pano_Auto/_auto/flash/Tourweaver_Courtyard_Pano.html)

Comment: I think all is actually good except for this one:  

http://caboleisure.com/panoramas/Courtyard_Pano_Auto/_auto/flash/sounds/system_music.mp3